# How to extract certain content of my doc files and convert it into excel in python

Tags: python, data-extraction

I got a doc file, and the example of my doc file content is like this:

```
Summary: Since 31 December 2019 and as of week 2022-17, 512 690 034 cases of COVID-19 (in accordance with the applied case definitions and testing strategies in the affected countries) have been reported, including 6 252 316 deaths.

Cases and deaths have been reported from:

Africa reported 11 682 207 confirmed cases (including South Africa 3 795 763 cases, Morocco 1 164 973 cases, Tunisia 1 040 193 cases, Egypt 515 645 cases and Libya 501 916 cases ...) and 252 868 deaths( including South Africa 100 363 deaths, Tunisia 28 550 deaths, Egypt 24 613 deaths, Morocco 16 069 deaths and Ethiopia 7 510 deaths...).

Asia reported 129 436 605 confirmed cases (including India 43 082 345 cases, South Korea 17 295 733 cases, Vietnam 10 653 526 cases, Japan 7 885 409 cases and Iran 7 221 653 ...) and 1 295 097 deaths(including India 523 869 deaths, Indonesia 156 273 deaths, Iran 141 083 deaths, Philippines 60 397 deaths and Vietnam 43 042 deaths...).

America: 153 644 865 cases(including United States 81 377 661 cases, Brazil 30 454 499 cases, Argentina 9 083 492 cases, Colombia 6 092 667 cases and Mexico 5 740 080 cases) and 2 729 595 deaths(including United States 993 744 deaths, Brazil 663 513 deaths, Mexico 324 350 deaths, Peru 212 865 deaths and Colombia 139 797 deaths...).
```

The ideal output should be like this:

```
|Continent   |Country     |Numbers   |Types of the Number|
|Africa      |SouthAfrica |3 795 763 |case
|Africa      |Morocco     |1 164 973 |case
|Africa      |Tunisia     |1 040 193 |case
|Africa      |Egypt       |515 645   |case
|Africa      |Libya       |501 916   |case
|Africa      |South Africa|100 363   |death
|Africa      |Tunisia     |28 550    |death
|Africa      |Egypt       |24 613    |death
|Africa      |Morocco     |16 069    |death
|Africa      |Ethiopia    |7 510     |death
|Asia        |India       |43 082 345|case
|Asia        |South Korea |17 295 733|case
|Asia        |Vietnam     |10 653 526|case
|Asia        |Japan       |7 885 409 |case
|Asia        |Iran        |7 221 653 |case
|Asia        |India       |523 869   |death
|Asia        |Indonesia   |156 273   |death
|Asia        |Iran        |141 083   |death
|Asia        |Philippines |60 397    |death
|Asia        |Vietnam     |43 042    |death
```

I have read the pandas cookbook and searched answers in the stackoverflow, but the answers are always not good enough for my needs. All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
x = "Africa reported 11 682 207 confirmed cases (including South Africa 3 795 763 cases, Morocco 1 164 973 cases, Tunisia 1 040 193 cases, Egypt 515 645 cases and Libya 501 916 cases "
TESTDATA = StringIO(x)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",|\(including", header=None)
df = df.transpose()
df = df[0].str.split(" ", expand = True)
df = df.replace("", np.nan)
df = df.ffill(axis = 0)
df
'''
output
'''
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0   Africa  reported    11  682 207 confirmed   cases   NaN
1   Africa  South   Africa  3   795 763 cases   NaN
2   Africa  Morocco 1   164 973 cases   cases   NaN
3   Africa  Tunisia 1   040 193 cases   cases   NaN
4   Africa  Egypt   515 645 cases   cases   cases   NaN
5   Africa  Libya   501 916 cases   cases   cases   NaN
```

This is the output for one line
You can do something similar to get this kind of dataframe and then preprocess it accordingly.